# Maria Db - Get most recent message from list of all messages where user Id = variable

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to get a list of the most recent messages for a perticular user. my tabe is as follows:

```
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| sender_user_id | int(11)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| remote_user_id | int(11)             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| message        | longtext            | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| read           | tinyint(4)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at     | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at     | timestamp           | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `messages` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `remote_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `message` longtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

This is what i've tried so far:
`SELECT sender_user_id, remote_user_id FROM messages m1 WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(m2.id) FROM messages m2 WHERE m1.sender_user_id = m2.sender_user_id AND m1.remote_user_id = m2.remote_user_id)`

Which seems close but obviously doesnt take into account the userId your searching for and it does sometimes return duplicates such as:

```
MariaDB [snowdon]> SELECT sender_user_id, remote_user_id FROM messages m1 WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(m2.id) FROM messages m2 WHERE m1.sender_user_id = m2.sender_user_id AND m1.remote_user_id = m2.remote_user_id)
    -> ;
+----------------+----------------+
| sender_user_id | remote_user_id |
+----------------+----------------+
|              1 |              2 |
|              2 |              1 |
|              3 |              1 |
+----------------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The first and second rows are a part of the same converation, so I'd only want the most recent to apear in the results.

Can someone help me write the SQL?

Thaks

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN m.sender_user_id = ? THEN m.remote_user_id ELSE m.sender_user_id END) as other_user_id
FROM messages m
WHERE ? IN (m.sender_user_id, m.remote_user_id) AND
      m.id = (SELECT MAX(m2.id)
              FROM messages m2
              WHERE (m2.sender_user_id, m2.remote_user_id) IN 
                      ( (m.sender_user_id, m.remote_user_id),
                        (m.remote_user_id, m.sender_user_id)
                      )
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any index, which can support an efficient search. So you should create the following two indexes: `(sender_user_id, remote_user_id, id)` and `(remote_user_id, sender_user_id, id)`. Now when you look for latest messages from or to user with id=123, you can use the following query:

```
select m.*
from (
    select max(id) as id
    from (
        select remote_user_id as user_id, max(id) as id
        from messages
        where sender_user_id = 123
        group by remote_user_id
        union all
        select sender_user_id as user_id, max(id) as id
        from messages
        where remote_user_id = 123
        group by sender_user_id
    ) u
    group by user_id
) g
join messages m using(id)
```